# How to use Facebook's conversion tracking pixel on iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, ads

I would like to use the Facebook Ad conversion tracking within an iOS app to track an event after the user installs.  Facebook has a method to do this on web pages through a Conversion Tracking Pixel, and I've looked through that JavaScript. It is making a GET request to offsite_event.php with the pixel ID:
https://www.facebook.com/offsite_event.php?id=6005000000&value=0

Obviously the pixel ID alone is not enough to know which Facebook user made the request.
So I assume this PHP is reading one of the facebook.com cookies to determine the user.

Can anyone at Facebook divulge which cookies this PHP code needs. 
"c_user" perhaps?

Answer (score 2):

To add to Michael's answer.

You done this using "App Events" instead of conversion pixel, which is for website.

To see additional event other than "App Install count" which is default objective for "App Install Ads".
Go to Ads manager > Report > Press "Edit Column" button > Navigate to Metric > Actions > Find Mobile Application category.

My full answer is also @ https://stackoverflow.com/a/26644170/4188314

Answer (score 1):

Facebook just added this functionality in the latest 3.2 iOS SDK update.

https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2013/02/25/facebook-sdk-3-2-for-ios/