# Facebook iOS Ads conversion tracking for purchase

Tags: ios, facebook

I was wondering if there is a way to tell how many people clicked on my Facebook Ads, install the app (Free), and make a purchase inside the app?

Right now, I've been using `[FBAppEvents logPurchase:[newAmount floatValue] currency:@"USD"];`, but I don't follow their logic...

10 days ago I made a test purchase, on the "Purchases" page in "Insights" it went to "No Facebook Identity" under "Identity Source". I thought it was correct because I did not install the app through clicking the ads. But somehow while I made another test purchase yesterday, it went to "Facebook App" under "Identity Source" which it suppose to be "No Facebook Identity"

I might have done something wrong or understanding the conversion tracking wrong... But is there a way that I can track "How many people purchase something inside the app after they clicked on Facebook ads"? Or is it even possibly doable? From my understanding App Store doesn't allow Facebook to send some parameters into our app so how would Facebook know?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm researching this in my project as well. I will share a clue I found.
I will write some extra info too, for someone who start from beginning. Skip any step you already done.

In my finding, Facebook SDK alone can track "IAP(In-app purchase) due to ads".

1. You just implement `[FBAppEvents logPurchase]` where it should be and of course any other app event you want in your app. (Don't forget to link Facebook app ID with your iOS app plist)
2. Test it if your app events are working, via looking at developer.facebook.com > Tools > Insight dashboard > Your app > App events > Show Most Recent Events. (In snowmen10 case, I assume it must be working by now)
3. Create FB ads of course, you may choose it as "Mobile app install ad" although your objective is to track IAP, I will show you later where the report is.
4. To see how much IAP result from ads, go to developer.facebook.com > Tools > Ads manager > Left most menu "Report". You will come across Facebook Ads Reporting page. Adjust Date or Filter until your ads show up.
5. See inside report table, you got date, campaign name, reach, click, actions, blah blah. Press "Edit Column" button. (next to Add Filter button)
6. Navigate to Metric > Actions > Find Mobile Application category > Mobile App purchase. You got new column to show how many "Purchase" event result from this ads!
7. The rest is up to you, test live ads, etc.

Note : About their logic, I think FB collect database how this FB account click which ads (ID) and that account emits app event later, and counts as sponsored from ads. etc...

But I don't certain about your "Identity Source", though.

Answer (score 1):

After a long time testing, here is some of my thoughts:

1. Since Apple cannot take any parameter to the store and there is no hook back, Facebook will not know who installed the app and who purchased the app in a `clean phone` environment even if you have the FB Event written inside... ... Meaning in a new phone and user has not login to facebook on the phone, and the ads link is sent indirectly, Facebook doesn't know (or not sure) about if the user actually install/purchase the app directly. This is where I see the metrics off...
2. But to be honest, the above scenario is rare... Most likely people would have a Facebook account to see Facebook ads, and by that they would know who downloaded it and purchased stuff... This works really well when user actually have facebook account in their "setting" page.
   However, there is still no distinguish between `user who download the app directly from the ads` v.s. `user who sees the ads, click on it to iTune store, close it, and manually search App Store, download the app and install/purchase it`. These 2 are considered ads impression although technically the later is "indirect".
3. If user doesn't have their account setup in the setting page, didn't download Facebook apps and just use the Safari to login to facebook, I realized metrics are wrong a few time...

But most importantly, when it is actually used in production, there will be many #2 and some #3 users, and since the numbers are high, there is really no way to find out if the metrics are 100% correct.

Comment: This was an old post but I would like to add that although it cannot distinguish between 2 cases in #2. I "THINK" they just note that certain user clicked on this ads then they use FBAppEvents emitted from app (install/launch events) to track those. If FB see those 2 events together after each other, that's mean user must clicked the ads and decided to install app after (by anymean, but who care? ). Just only my speculation.